# In Next.js, How to use Image (next/image) in Link (next/link)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to use Next.js framework to make my latest project.
I use Image tag from next/image in Link tag from next/link,
But I got the error like below.

```
next-dev.js?3515:24 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(LinkComponent)`.
```

My code was like below.

```
export defult function header (){
 return {
   <div>
     <Link href="/">
          <Image
            src="http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx.com"
            objectFit="contain"
            layout="fill"
          />
      </Link>
   </div>
 }
}
```

I read the [official documents](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag) and use 'passHref' tag at Link,
and change code like below.

```
export defult function header (){
 return {
   <div>
     <Link href="/" passHref>
          <Image
            src="http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx.com"
            objectFit="contain"
            layout="fill"
          />
      </Link>
   </div>
 }
}
```

But still error ocurrred.
Does anyone advice how to stop this kind of error, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `passHref` is if you have a custom component that wraps an `a`. For an image you don't need this but you do  need an `a` tag, i.e.:

```
export default function Header() {
  return {
    <div>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          <Image
            src="http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx.com"
            objectFit="contain"
            layout="fill"
          />
        </a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: In next.js 13 this won't work

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Pilaton! In version 13 the `<a>` is no longer required as `<Link>` will always render one. There is a [Next blog post here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#nextlink) that covers this and a code mod.